# graphql, union scalar type?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

The `payload` field can be `Int` or `String` scalar type.
when I write it like union type:

```js
const schema = `
  input QuickReply {
    content_type: String
    title: String
    payload: Int | String
    image_url: String
  }
`
```

I got an error:

```sh
GraphQLError: Syntax Error GraphQL request (45:18) Expected Name, found |

    44:     title: String
    45:     payload: Int | String
                         ^
    46:     image_url: String
```

It seems `GraphQL` does not support the union scalar type.

So, how can I solve this situation?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Scalars can't be used as part of unions, since per the specification, unions specifically "represent an object that could be one of a list of GraphQL Object types." Instead, you can use a custom scalar. For example:

```
const MAX_INT = 2147483647
const MIN_INT = -2147483648
const coerceIntString = (value) => {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    throw new TypeError(`IntString cannot represent an array value: [${String(value)}]`)
  }
  if (Number.isInteger(value)) {
    if (value < MIN_INT || value > MAX_INT) {
      throw new TypeError(`Value is integer but outside of valid range for 32-bit signed integer: ${String(value)}`)
    }
    return value
  }
  return String(value)
}
const IntString = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'IntString',
  serialize: coerceIntString,
  parseValue: coerceIntString,
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    if (ast.kind === Kind.INT) {
      return coerceIntString(parseInt(ast.value, 10))
    }
    if (ast.kind === Kind.STRING) {
      return ast.value
    }
    return undefined
  }
})
```

This code effectively combines the behaviors for both the Int and String types, while still enforcing the range for 32-bit signed integers. However, you could have whatever type coercion behavior you want. Check out [the source code](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/15.x.x/src/type/scalars.js) to see how the built-in scalars work, or [this article](https://medium.com/graphql-mastery/how-to-design-graphql-queries-and-mutations-part-3-custom-scalars-78d441869258) for more details around how custom scalars work.

Note that if you're trying to return one of several scalars for an *output* field, it's possible to utilize a union for the *parent* type to achieve a similar result. For example, this isn't possible:

```
type Post {
  content: String | Int
}
```

but you can do the following:

```
type PostString {
  content: String
}

type PostInt {
  content: Int
}

union Post = PostString | PostInt
```

Comment: Super interesting answer!!! I couldn't find such a relevant example anywhere else....

Comment: That sounds like a good solution for mixing multiple scalars. In my case there is a response of a task, and it may be either scalar (Int, String) or object type. I could use scalar JSON instead of object types, but JSON does not validate internal fields and can't guarantee they are in the response, and not an option.  
So I ran into the same issue, but it seems that this solution won't work for something like:   
`union = String | Int | MyTypeOne | MyTypeTwo ... MyTypeTen`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Mihail Instead of using a JSON scalar, you could still create a custom scalar with validation specific to your use case baked in. Outside of that, if you're using this for an output type, you can use a union for the parent type as described above.

Comment: This union solution doesn't actually work exactly. If you try it you'll find the following error: `Fields "content" conflict because they return conflicting types "String" and "Boolean". Use different aliases on the fields to fetch both if this was intention`

It turns out the "content" field name has to be different for each, which is pretty ugly, but the only way to make this work.