# How do I specify a graphql type that takes multiple types?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I want to create a graphql type that can return either an `Array of Integers` or `String`.

I've already tried using union in the form
`union CustomVal = [Int] | String`, but this returns an error.

The schema declaration is:

```
union CustomValues = [Int] | String

type Data {
    name: String
    slug: String
    selected: Boolean
    values: CustomValues
}
```

The error is:

```
node_modules/graphql/error/syntaxError.js:24
return new _GraphQLError.GraphQLError('Syntax Error: ' + description, undefined, source, [position]);
Syntax Error: Expected Name, found [
GraphQL request (81:23)
80: 
81:     union CustomValues = [Int] | String
```

Is this possible to do in graphql? If not, can you please suggest an alternative to do this.

I ask this as the union documentation says that `Note that members of a union type need to be concrete object types; you can't create a union type out of interfaces or other unions.`

Any solutions would be highly helpful.

Comment: Can you try removing `[]` from `[Int]`?

Comment: Still throws an error, and I want the type to either take an `Array of Integers` or a `String`, and isn't array type declared in graphql using `[]`?

The error is `Union type CustomValues can only include Object types, it cannot include Int. Union type CustomValues can only include Object types, it cannot include String.`

Comment: You need to use `[]` if you want a list (array), but if you want to return different types on different inputs then you'll have to define how to do that in your resolver function.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I am currently having a similar issue when I want to create a Union type that accepts an object and an array of this object, and I get an error that it is not possible to use array in a Union type..

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Follow this https://github.com/facebook/graphql/issues/215, Graphql does not support scalar union types currently, you can do this

```
union IntOrString = IntBox | StringBox

type IntBox {
  value: Int
}

type StringBox {
  value: String
}
```

or you can have your custom type, see this [graphql, union scalar type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49897319/graphql-union-scalar-type)

Answer (score 0):

As per [Graphql specification](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Unions),

> The member types of a Union type must all be Object base types.
> Scalar, Interface and Union types must not be member types of a Union.

Then instead of "**union**", you can use custom scalar to solve this use-case. Since any scalar type is valid JSON, hence we can use a custom JSON scalar here.

You can use this package [graphql-type-json](https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json) for custom scalar json type.

```
scalar JSON

type Data {
  name: String
  slug: String
  selected: Boolean
  values: JSON
}
```

In this way, you can associate any scalar values (*i.e. Int, Float, String etc..*) or its array associations (*i.e. [Int], [String], etc..*) with member "***Data.values***" without violating the specifications.