# Is it possible to mix Scalar and Object types in Union

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to create a Union that takes object types along with custom scalar types (like `JSON`).
For example:

```
union MyUnion = MyType | JSON
type MyResult {
  id: ID!
  result: MyUnion!
}
type Query {
  result: MyResult!
}
```

But when I add it to Apollo Server I get this error
`Union type MyUnion can only include Object types, it cannot include JSON.`.

2 questions:
* is it an issue in Apollo Server (couldn't find it in GQL specs)
* can this be done with Union or are there any other legit ways?

Comment: Only object types can be part of a union, as the error indicates. At best, you can utilize a custom scalar as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49897319/graphql-union-scalar-type) or create an object type with a single field that's the scalar in question and then use that inside the union.

Comment: Thank you @DanielRearden, should have find that myself. Though as I mentioned in that issue, in my case there is a mix of multiple object types and custom/native scalar. Making it work though another custom scalar doesn't seem reasonable, because I may end up with a thousand-line-of-code custom resolver. The only working solution I found is to use JSON instead of object types and do validation myself on the client side. This is a bad solution, but I don't have another one at the moment.

Comment: Like I said, it's possible to wrap the scalar in an object type. So you could have something like `type JSONObject { json: JSON }` and then use that as part of a union.