# How to use different scalar types for one field in graphQL schema?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-schema

I have an input type that says:

```
input testInput {
a: String 
b: String
c: Boolean
}
```

I have a situation where field `c` can be either `String` or `Boolean`.
How can i implement the field `c` that will accept both  `String` and `Boolean` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49897319/graphql-union-scalar-type

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types

Answer (score 0):

Graphql does not support union of scalar types.
So you can modify it this way

input testInput {
a: String
b: String
c: hybridType
}

type cBoolean {
content: Boolean
}

type cString {
content: String
}

union hybridType = cBoolean | cString